# jQuery bind each to dynamically populated elements

Tags: jquery, dynamic, bind, each

The folowing scenario:

On a ajax return I'd like to change some links in the document. Some of them are hardcoded others dynamically generated.

```
function( data ) {
   $('a.imageselect').each(function() {
      var imgValue = $(this).attr('href');
      $(this).attr('href', imgValue.replace('publish_img', 'edit_img/'+data.dbid));
   });
}
```

It works like supposed with the hardcoded elements, but not with those:

```
$("#chooseimg").after('<a href="'+imgUrl+'" class="imageselect">foo</a>");
```

I know that maybe "on" could help me - but I dont know how to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".button-delete", function() {
    console.log("inside");
});
```

The uses of .on is the above but i think in this case you need to create a function for

```
function my_func() {
    $('a.imageselect').each(function() {
     var imgValue = $(this).attr('href');
     $(this).attr('href', imgValue.replace('publish_img', 'edit_img/'+data.dbid));
    });
}
```

and call this after adding the dynamic data.

```
$("#chooseimg"]).after('<a href="'+imgUrl+'" class="imageselect">foo</a>');
my_func();
```

like this.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand you, but the point is - the links are already populated wenn I get the ajax return. So it would not make sense to fire the function right after the creation of the links (at this time "data.dbid" is still unknown). It did not change anything when my replace-function was in a seperate function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Maybe you using old version of the jQuery.
I tested your code in this script and anything works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        var imgUrl = 'publish_img';
        $("#chooseimg").after('<a href="'+imgUrl+'" class="imageselect">foo</a>');
    });

    $('#button2').on('click', function() {
        change('1');
    });
});

function change( data ) {
   $('a.imageselect').each(function() {
      var imgValue = $(this).attr('href');
      $(this).attr('href', imgValue.replace('publish_img', 'edit_img/'+data));
   });
}
</script>

<input type="button" id="button" name="add" value="Add link!" /><br />
<input type="button" id="button2" name="change" value="Change" />

<div id="chooseimg">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```